# Adding Custom Control Into TListView In Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Can I add custom control into TListView other than the official provided in Firemonkey Delphi, if can, how to do it?

Comment: TListView in FMX is not designed to accept controls. Perhaps if you describe exactly what you want to achieve, someone might be able to help you